# if image tag 'dark' change #main-nav color

Tags: jquery, wordpress, colors, slider, nav

I'm trying to run an if/else statement if img in .slotholder has an alt tag of 'dark' then I would like the ".menu > li a" to change color to white as the text gets lost in the img slider behind it, I would also like to have else nav color is black.

Im trying to achive this using either image title or image tag cause my page is built on wordpress and this will give me the option to tell the nav which image it needs to respond to from the admin side.

Pretty much in the end I want it to and up looking like the saturdays NYC home page - http://www.saturdaysnyc.com/

**HTML**

<.slotholder>

```
< img src="..." alt="dark" data-fullwidthcentering="on" class="defaultimg" style="width:
2008px; height: 1338.33984375px; position: absolute; left: -25px; top: -369px; opacity:         1;">
```

< />

**CSS**

```
nav .menu > li a{
color:black;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
if ($('.defaultimg').attr('tag') == 'dark') {
//im not sure what function to put in here to result in the nav changing color

}


else { $( '.defaultimg' ).click(function() {
//change .menu > li a color to black

 }



});
```

I am very new to jquery so Im sorry if my explaining makes very little sense.

Thank you thank you thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the alt tag which should actually be used for alternative text, why not just add a class in the HTML code?

Not only this, but also using JavaScript to do this will mean the user might see a flash of the old formatting whilst the page renders, before the JavaScript has had a chance to run.

Comment: Im not a master at PHP and this is a wordpress site and also I was hoping to use either the image title or tag as I can decide what color the nav will have to turn by putting in 'dark' or 'light' when uploading the image to wordpress.

Comment: with that said, maybe I could set up an adClass with an array and just have a fixed formatted sequence like first,second can be 'dark' and the third will be light ect...  sorry to be so amateur